# Vertically align text in an inline element

Tags: html, css

## Problem

So I'm creating a simple navigation menu which contains a `div` of `a` tags. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

The follow are my HTML and CSS:

HTML

```
<div id="tabcontent-container">
    <div class="tabcontent-menu">
        <a href="#">WLAN Jumpstart</a>
        <a href="#">Mobility</a>
        <a href="#">Guest Access Jumpstart</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#tabcontent-container { padding: 15px 0px; position: relative; text-align: center; border-radius: 25px; -webkit-border-radius: 25px; }
.tabcontent-menu {}
.tabcontent-menu a { text-decoration: none; color: white; font-size: 30px; border-right: 1px solid white; line-height: 33px; padding: 0 22px; display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 70px; vertical-align: top; }
.tabcontent-menu a:last-child { border:none; }
.tabcontent-menu a:hover { color:#000; }
```

Working example on [Jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/H9VHs/)

## The Question

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to align the middle "Mobility" `a` tag to the middle.  The other two links look fine because they are double line. I purposely made them double line for a reason, and now just need the middle one to middle align some how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align: middle` to adjust the position vertically. Since that only works on table cells, set `display: table-cell` for the `.tabcontent-menu a`

http://jsfiddle.net/H9VHs/8/

Comment: Note that @Chris version will break when shrinking the window while the `table-cell` version will adjust nicely.

Comment: Leave the comment on the answer, then; it makes no sense on YOUR answer :). But, when it comes down to that, the `table-cell` method does not evenly distribute extra space among the items, whereas it does so in the `line-height` version (try it -- shrink and expand the viewport for both versions). As indicated in the articles I link to, there are several ways to skin this cat, each with pros and cons. That said, +1, this is one of the valid ways.

Comment: @Chris: true so, just pointing out the pros of my solution :) BTW: it's easy to set `width: 33%` and it will evenly distribute the extra space http://jsfiddle.net/H9VHs/28/

Comment: The `width: 33%` put you over the top. I was trying to center align the text again using the display:table-cell , and couldn't figure it out.  Thanks.

Comment: (don't learn the wrong lesson from this and start using tables for layout :p)

Comment: Oh geez, we shan't get into this age-old debate here, but I will just leave these here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html, http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/, and http://www.chromaticsites.com/blog/13-reasons-why-css-is-superior-to-tables-in-website-design/

Answer (score 2):

I usually accomplish something like this by varying the `line-height`.

```
.tabcontent-menu a.midline {
 line-height: 64px;   
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/PZVnq/

**Documentation/Further Reading**

- CSS `line-height` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height
- Lauri Raittilan on Vertical centering with CSS - http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/
- Vertical centering with CSS on vanseodesign.com - http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: I like your idea, however I don't want to use a class for this, as sometimes it might be more than 3 menu items in the content.

Comment: @Romes The advantage of a class is that you can add the class to any item that has single-row text. Any item without the class will have normal line height. Check out the articles there -- there's several ways to accomplish this, you aren't alone in fighting this layout challenge!

Comment: I see what you mean.  I'm using this in a Wordpress loop, so sometimes there are 5 menu items. Would you just check with javascript the height of the text and if it was single line, just add the class to it? Thanks for the articles I'll check them out.

Comment: @Romes Ah, dynamic menu items... that's a different matter. In that case, you really should check out Horen's method, that's mentioned in those articles as a possible route, and it would probably work better with dynamic items. As long as IE7 isn't one of your target user agents (and I wouldn't blame you if it isn't), that way works well too. If you DO have to support older IE, then yes, you would have to work with some mechanism of measuring line length to decide whether the class is needed or not, either server- or client-side.

Comment: agreed. Client hasn't mentions IE7, so we will go with Horen's method for now :)

Comment: Um, this doesn't work on inline elements at all, right? What am I missing?

Comment: @Protectorone The element in the OP's code has a CSS class that is adding block type display onto the element in question. You are correct that this does not work on inline elements -- inline-block is good though.

Comment: @Chris: Oh, I see now. Thanks. The title of the question had me confused.